# Recurring select (ice cube gem) in React

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ice-cube

I'm trying to migrate my Rails front end to React and need to import the recurring select gem to React. Don't seem to find a stable npm package for this rails gem.

How would I import this ruby gem into React through webpacker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up basing my code on this repo - https://github.com/colinwahl/react-recurring-select